# Direct3D availability in DirectX

Tags: graphics-card, directx

What **exactly** gives an XP machine the ability to have Direct3D to be enabled/disabled in DirectX 9c?  Is it the video card driver?  Motherboard driver?  Something related to a Windows/.Net Update? A combination of things?

I have a number of computers that don't have the ability to have Direct3D enabled or disabled in DXDiag and a small number that can.  The computers are all part of a lab and have *very* similar setups (I can't say they're 100% the same, but really close). I think I can fix things if I know what gives an XP machine the ability to use Direct3D.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve here? Has Direct3D been disabled on your card? If so ask that question, but we'd need to know what card and what OS.

Comment: The issues is Direct3D isn't "installed" on some of the machines.

They're all running WinXP SP3 and NVidia 8600GT video cards and DirectX 9c.  The graphics settings are the same on each machine as far as hardware acceleration and write combining and they're all using the latest non-beta driver available from NVidia.

Answer (score 0):

Direct3D is part of Microsoft's DirectX application programming interface. Thus - if you have DirectX, you must have (in common) Direct3D